# Eclipse CDT Remote Debugging ("Attach to Applicaton" or "Remote Application")

Tags: eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging, eclipse-cdt, gdbserver

I just created a Amazon EC2 due to limited ram size on my workstation. Thus I need to figure out how to conduct remote debugging on this remote instance.

First of all, I am not quite sure I understand the difference between "Attach to Applicaton" or "Remote Application" in debugging configuration tab. From what I've learned, the first one is just using Eclipse as a front-end GUI to connect a remote gdbserver. But I have no idea what the second one means.

Right now I can connect to the gdbserver on my EC2. However, gdbserver gives me a warning message

```
Could not load vsyscall page because no executable was specified
try using the "file" command first.
```

I've already defined the executable as well as project in Eclipse's debugging page. Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score -1):

I have done the same thing some time back and it was working absolutely fine and I have mentioned all the step in my blog. Check the [link](http://waheedtechblog.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-do-jvm-remote-debugging-via-ssh.html) for detail description.

Comment: The question is about native remote debugging with Eclipse-CDT and gdbserver. The blog post you linked here is about Java remote debugging.